# How to control speed of tests using Selenium WebDriver with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium IDE, there is a 'Speed Control' to control speed of tests (i.e. by setting that speed, we can set time interval (not exact time) between execution of two selenium commands)

Is there any Ruby api to do same using Selenium WebDriver?

Answer (score 0):

> try out the gem 'cucumber-ajaxer', by this Cucumber should wait for AJAX calls
>   in @javascript Scenarios

Comment: Could you please give an example how to use it?

Comment: just add '@javascript' tag above Scenario which has to wait for ajax response eg: -


@javascript
Scenario: Check Cart Update

Comment: Actually, I don't want to wait for ajax responses. I've to keep constant time say 500 milliseconds between execution of two selenium commands.

Comment: look at the available cucumber hooks
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks